# Microsoft SharePoint: Is there an API for uploading a List fast?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-list, power-platform

I have a problem, that I want to write a Client-Application, which uploads a CSV-File with about 700 lines to a SharePoint Online-List. I just found the function to upload a single line to a SharePoint list in Microsofts Graph & SharePoint API. This works but takes forever, as I have to wait for the respond of the server, before uploading the next line.
Is there an API or some way to parse and upload the CSV-File as whole into a SharePoint-Online list in order to get my Application working faster?
I just can't believe, that this is the only way to handle this problem.

Best regards
Chrissi

Answer (score 0):

try this
It updates the SharePoint List from CSV
Maybe you can use similar logic.

https://sshareasolutions.com/2020/04/25/update-sharepoint-list-with-csv-file-using-jquery/